# what are pros and cons of upgrading from JRE5 to JRE8?

Tags: java

My current server system has JRE5. We are setting up a new server system and planning to upgrade from JRE 5 to JRE7 or JRE8. I tried to check which one is better to install but couldn't decide anything. 
Can any one explain me the pros&cons of JRE 8 over JRE5 and which version is better to install?

Thank you.

Comment: JRE 8 is better to install as it is faster and supported.  The downside is your web server might not support Java 8, in which case you should use a supported version.

Comment: I would generally use Java 7, just because that's the version most people have

Comment: you could visit this url, which would assit you in listing all the pros and cons for JRE8.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8all-relnotes-2226344.html

Comment: @JClassic, I'm not sure that's been true for a ~year, maybe more. I think it was surveyed last year that only ~35% of Java developers had not began using it where possible.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Oracle Java SE Support Roadmap](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html), Java 7 will no longer have public updates after April 2015. That is this month. I would suggest upgrading to Java 8. More modern versions of the JRE generally offer better performance, offer additional programming APIs and features. Finally, if you are going to upgrade then (without a compelling reason to target a lower release) the current release is best.

Answer (score 0):

Also don't forget security updates. The supported versions will get security updates, but the unsupported ones will likely not receive these updates, hence leaving your machine and applications potentially vulnerable. If my memory serves me right, JRE6 and 7 have had a very high number of security related fixes.